# Creating a raster file from a kernel smooth with differing x,y resolutions

Tags: r, gis, raster, kernel-density, r-raster

I have a set of GPS data which I am attempting to kernel smooth using the bkde2d in the 'kernsmooth' package. I have used the Hpi bandwidth estimator in the 'ks' package to determine my bandwidth however when I run the kernel smooth and convert the resulting list into a raster the resulting product appears to have differing x, y resolutions and is therefore impossible to export as an ascii. It is also impossible to read this raster into a GIS tool when exporting as a GRD file as it appears to be corrupt, presumably due to having differing resolutions.

Here is some sample code from my run. My data is projected in UTM30, WGS84:

```
bnd=Hpi(x=cbind(GPS$lon, GPS$lat))
coord <- cbind(GPS$lon, GPS$lat)

est <- bkde2D(coord, bandwidth=bnd, gridsize = c(4000L, 4000L))

est.raster = raster(list(x=est$x1,y=est$x2,z=est$fhat))
projection(est.raster) <- CRS("+proj=utm +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +zone=30 +north +units=km")`
xmin(est.raster) <- min(GPS$lon)
xmax(est.raster) <- max(GPS$lon)
ymin(est.raster) <- min(GPS$lat)
ymax(est.raster) <- max(GPS$lat)

writeRaster(est.raster, "kerntest", format='ascii')
```

The resulting raster layer looks like this:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 4000, 4000, 1.6e+07  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.03242282, 0.03011303  (x, y)
extent      : 415.2883, 544.9796, 6371.946, 6492.398  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +zone=30 +units=km +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 0.005935748  (min, max)
```

However when I attempt to export it I get the error message:

```
Error in .startAsciiWriting(x, filename, ...) : 
  x has unequal horizontal and vertical resolutions. Such data cannot be stored in arc-ascii format
```

My question is why are my resolutions different and how should I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resample the raster to a new raster with equal x and y resolutions. You may lose some information this way. Alternatively you could make sure your gridsize in bkde2D would divide the x and y extents equally.

```
est.raster <- raster::resample(est.raster, raster(ext=extent(c(415.2883, 544.9796, 6371.946, 6492.398)),resolution=0.03,crs=projection(est.raster))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your example (including that we cannot reproduce it!). It should be something like this:

```
library(ks)
library(KernSmooth)
library(raster)

set.seed(0)
GPS <- data.frame(lon=runif(100), lat=runif(100)*2)
#bnd <- Hpi(GPS)
est <- bkde2D(GPS, bandwidth=0.1, gridsize = c(400L, 400L))

names(est) <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
est.raster <- raster(est)
# do not change the extent! 
projection(est.raster) <- "+proj=utm +zone=30 +north +units=km +datum=WGS84"

writeRaster(est.raster, "kerntest", format='ascii')
```

There is nothing wrong with this object. But the file format you chose to use cannot save these data. Use another format! E.g.:

```
writeRaster(est.raster, "kerntest.tif")
```

You could also try to force bkde2D to produce a raster with square cells, using `range.x`

```
est <- bkde2D(GPS, bandwidth=0.1, gridsize = c(400L, 800L), range.x=list(c(1/800,1-1/800), c(1/800,2-1/800)))

names(est) <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
est.raster <- raster(est)
projection(est.raster) <- "+proj=utm +zone=30 +north +units=km +datum=WGS84"

writeRaster(est.raster, "kerntest", format='ascii')
```